# When tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths the contentoffset changed

Tags: ios, swift

in my custom `UITableViewController`,  in `viewDidLoad()` I setted `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
then when I call  the `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`,the contentoffset changed,how can I fix it? Thanks!

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName:"PostCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PunchCardCell")

func handlePostChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let object = notification.object as? Post {
        for (index, post) in posts.enumerate() {
            if post.objectId == object.objectId {
                if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
                    post.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(userInfo as! [String : AnyObject])
                }
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you scroll the tableView before reloading row?

Comment: no,I just tap a button and post a Notification

Comment: Set contentOffset to (0,0) again after reload.

Comment: are you using AutoLayout properties ? if yes then issue should be there

Comment: @Muneeba I want to keep the contentOffset but not to change it,and the tableView.reloadData() won't change contentOffset,it only happen when tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths